# GIT push tag second remote

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag

Is it possible to have a local repository with two remotes while **remoteA** is used to develop while on **remoteB** I only want to have the relese tags but without the history. Say, for the third tags I have a lot of commits on **remoteA** but only three commits on **remoteB** (tags + master).

Thanks

Comment: Git is entirely built on the concept of history...........the second you have a repository without the history (i.e. just the release commits).........then you basically have a new repository....................what are you trying to accomplish by this workflow?

Comment: Certainly I can simply copy the code after I have done the release and I will of course also have the release in the second repository but not intermediate steps...The reason is that sometimes it happens that I commit confidential stuff but I still want to provide the code in an easy way....Seems that I simply will copy the release code and commit to the second repo.

Comment: If you' are trying for that approach, then you can simply squash  and rebase all those commits to just the few you are requiring and could push THOSE commits to a new remote..........but my question is why you are wanting to do this?

Comment: Above this is the actual reason but I was also interested if such a thing is possible with just a second remote on my repository.

Comment: if you committed sensitive information then this is a very common problem......there are existing solutions to this problem that are worth checking out on google........i recommend not doing the approach you are seeking. hope it helps.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", it is possible. You can have as many remotes as you want, where you may push arbitrary commits to any of your remotes

Comment: I think there are ways to use `reset` such that you get your sandbox with the files in the state you want from B to create the commit you want for A. Effectively, that would be identical to copying, but maybe more convenient?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git reset` with a path to effectively copy the files from a commit on `remoteB` to your current state. If you're currently sitting on the commit at the HEAD of `remoteA`, that might do what you want.

Let's assume you have the latest release state in `remoteB/releaseN`.

Let's also assume you have a branch called `published` on `remoteA`, where you want to push one commit jumping right to `remoteB/releaseN` without the history.

**The recipe**

```sh
git checkout published       # must have remoteA/published as upstream
git merge remoteA/published  # just in case, to make sure it's in sync
cd <root directory of your sandbox>
git reset remoteB/releaseN -- .
git commit -m"jumping to releaseN"
git push remoteA published
git reset --hard
```

**Explanations**

- In the first two commands, I'm just making sure you're on branch `published`, with should have `remoteA/published` as its upstream, and be up to date to with.
- The `git reset remoteB/releaseN -- .` command, run from the root directory of your sandbox, "copies" all files in `.` from their state in `remoteB/releaseN` to the cache, though it does not change your working files. So a `commit` here will create the commit you want, with no history, which you can then push.
- Since the `reset` operation didn't change the files in the sandbox, only the cache, I added a hard reset at the end, to sync your sandbox with the commit you just made.

**Limitations**

This technique only creates the "copy" commits. If you wanted tags too, manually recreate and push them in a different sandbox with only `remoteA` as remote if you want the same names. If you try to push them from your sandbox with the two remotes with the same names, you'd have a collision since those tags are pointing to unrelated commits between the two remotes.

Comment: I'd actually use `git commit-tree` (plus a few additional operations) to build the second history for remote B, but yes, this should work.